# Use SQL or/and PHP in order to SUM a quantity and insert the values into the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need these tables to be updated permanently, not a sort by or a group by to show the quantitys, after I run the commands or use PHP i need the table it self to be manipulated have the updated values, so I can click on and off the table itself and the table will have been manipulated, thank you for reading.

Current table:

| Names | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| James | 1 |
| James | 1 |
| James | 1 |
| Julia | 1 |
| Julia | 1 |
| Jamie | 1 |

What I want:

| Names | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| James | 3 |
| Julia | 2 |
| Jamie | 1 |

I am using SQL however it is a WebApp that im using PHP for another part of it, so I don't mind going down that route if needed

I have already tried using "SUM" however this only temporarily changes the table, I need certain commands I can use so the table stays with the updated quantities.

Any ideas would be amazing, thank you.

Comment: `I need these tables to be updated permanently`...why? This sounds like an arbitrary requirement you've invented for yourself. What advantage do you think it will give you compared to what you have now? After all, you can just use a SUM query whenever you want to see the totals, so that's not an issue. Having the original data is a good audit trail if you need to look at what was entered, and is also more flexible because you can query it in other ways too, to get different information, (e.g. counts, averages etc etc). I don't see anything to be gained by destroying that.

Comment: @ADyson If I just use something as simple as SUM these values are only on my screen temporarily, nobody else can see these updates.

Comment: @ADyson I have many of my tables, all different names, quantities e.t.c, what I need to do is merge all these together (I have with PHP) - but having loads of quantity 1's is making the spreadsheet look awful and also takes up more space, If I update these values permanently when I go to merge all the tables I will have much cleaner rows, if that makes sense, ty for the comment and helping

Comment: `these values are only on my screen temporarily, nobody else can see these updates`...anyone else with access to the database could also run the same query, and can get the latest results when they do so. You can even make a web page which does it for them, if you like. No-one else in the world destroys their raw data and replaces it with aggregate data, it's a bad idea. Of course if you want to create a time-series history, you could write the sum to a history table with a date so you can see the totals at different points in time, but that's slightly different than what you seem to be asking

Comment: `having loads of quantity 1's is making the spreadsheet look awful`...what spreadsheet is that? We were talking about a database, I thought. If you're exporting data from the database to a spreadsheet and you don't want the raw data, then simply export the result of your SUM query, instead of the raw table.

Comment: `I have many of my tables, all different names, quantities `....why? If you have lots of tables with the same column names, then that's a design flaw, and it means your data is denormalised. Take a tutorial or course to learn about proper relational database design, so you won't make fundamental design mistakes which then lead to bigger problems later.

Comment: `If I update these values permanently when I go to merge all the tables I will have much cleaner rows`...again it's unnecessary. Don't worry about the appearance of the raw data. Just use queries / views to present that data to the world in the way you want to.

Comment: @ADyson I am the only one who has access to the database nobody else has, I automate my WebApp so it makes other spreadsheets into these types of databases, it configures them using SQL then sends out a configured total version, which I can download from my App - I need the total spreadsheet to update instead of a temporary command which does nothing but show me the query. How would you go about writing the SUM to save to a different table? That could work.

Comment: @ADyson We are talking about a database, these databases link to a spreadsheet which I export using my App, all databases are slightly different, some automatically have quantitys installed so I dont have to do this - however If I have a spreadsheet with some of the quantitys working and some not, it looks stupid.

Comment: I'm not really sure what all that means without seeing an example. But again, if you don't want the raw data in your spreadsheet, then don't link the spreadsheet to the raw tables. Instead, link it to a view which returns the SUMmed data.

Comment: @ADyson So at the moment I have 10 different tables, once I configure them I load up a PHP page and I type "insert values from table into FINAL_TABLE" - I do this with all of my tables so my "Final_Table" is huge and contains all the small tables in one big table. I understand this is weird, don't judge me. Other than "select quantity(sum) group by name" is there any other command I could do to insert this data into a table? I understand this isn't the easiest thing to understand, I'm awful at explaining, im sorry

Comment: `I have 10 different tables`...but why? Just have FINAL_TABLE **to start with**.  is there any other command I could do to insert this data into a table?`... again, why do you **want** to insert it into a table? How does that help you? Like I said before, you can just run the SUM query whenever you need to know the information. If you want to be able to easily run the query again, or let others run it, then [create a view](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx) to store the query, and you can then call it _as if it was a table_.

Comment: I think maybe you need to take a course on relational database design or something, because you seem to be missing a few key concepts, e.g. how to normalise your tables, the rules that you don't store the same type of data in two different tables, you don't duplicate data, and (unless you're having massive performance issues) you don't store data in tables which you could derive simply by running a SELECT query on some other data. Those are basic core principles, but your proposal violates them, for no obvious reason. Please try to follow the established ways and you'll have an easier time.